# How to add a class to the first paragraph of all the classes?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a piece of code that works but only for the first paragraph. I want to add a class and wrap in another class the first paragraph of all the classes `service-more`

I'm a beginner at jQuery so I have no clue why this happens. Do I need a loop?

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xxrr5/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the class by it self first then use find:

```
$('.service-more').find('p:first').addClass('service-right-p-first').wrap('<div class="service-right-p-first2" />');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xxrr5/1/

Comment: Thank you! It was so simple :D

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/Xxrr5/3/ here you are

```
$('p:first','.service-more').CODE HERE
```

**this works fine.. jquery takes care of the rest**

Comment: I'd suspect it was because your answer was a link to an external site, without that answer being available here. (I didn't down-vote, and in fact up-voted; but that's the only reason I could think of). Also, it's worth noting that `$('p:first','.service-more')`, in jQuery, is internally converted to `$('.service-more').find('p:first')`, so it might be (a ***little***) faster to use the latter version.

Answer (score 1):

Use `first-child` instead of `first`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xxrr5/4/

Comment: Damn -- everybody beat me to it.

Comment: What is the difference between first-child and first here?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/Xxrr5/6/

```
$('.service-more').find("p:first").addClass('service-right-p-first').wrap('<div class="service-right-p-first2" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.service-more p:first").addClass('calssName').wrap("<div class='className1' >");
```